Shortcut Redirect In loop iOS - Shortcut
I have implement shortcut. If target app open then open my app using shortcut.
So I have facing issue going in loop.
This is correct behaviour,

Open target app
Open my app
Again open target app (now target app already in background)
Again open my app.

We expected behaviours,

Open target app
Open my app
Again open target app (now target app already in background)
No need to again redirect to my app because app is in background.

Here is my code for shortcut.
import AppIntents
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUICore
import UIKit
//
// These will be the options in the Shortcut action to open a book or navigate to the library
enum NavigationType: String, AppEnum, CaseDisplayRepresentable {
    case library
    case book

    // This will be displayed as the title of the menu shown when picking from the options
  @available(iOSApplicationExtension 16, *)
  static var typeDisplayRepresentation = TypeDisplayRepresentation(name: "Navigation")
    
  @available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *)
  static var caseDisplayRepresentations: [Self:DisplayRepresentation] = [
        .library: DisplayRepresentation(title: "Library",
                                        subtitle: "Return to the home page",
                                        image: .init(systemName: "books.vertical")),
        .book: DisplayRepresentation(title: "Book",
                                     subtitle: "Navigate to a specific book",
                                     image: .init(systemName: "book"))
    ]
}
// Enum to represent the static book options
enum AppOption: String, AppEnum, CaseDisplayRepresentable {
    case youtube = "YouTube"
    case facebook = "Facebook"
    case twitter = "Twitter"

    @available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *)
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation = TypeDisplayRepresentation(name: "App")

    @available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *)
    static var caseDisplayRepresentations: [Self: DisplayRepresentation] = [
        .youtube: DisplayRepresentation(title: "YouTube",
                                       subtitle: "com.google.ios.youtube"),
        .facebook: DisplayRepresentation(title: "Facebook",
                                        subtitle: "com.facebook.ios"
                                        ),
        .twitter: DisplayRepresentation(title: "Twitter",
                                       subtitle: "com.twitter.ios")
    ]
}


// Struct to represent an app
struct App {
    let appName: String
    let bundleID: String
    let deepLinking:String
}

// Sample app data (you can load this dynamically in the future)
let appsDetail = [
  App(appName: "YouTube", bundleID: "com.google.ios.youtube",deepLinking:"youtube://"),
    App(appName: "Facebook", bundleID: "com.facebook.ios",deepLinking:"fb://"),
    App(appName: "Twitter", bundleID: "com.twitter.ios",deepLinking:"twitter://")
]

@available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *)
struct OpenBook: AppIntent {
  
  // Title o  f the action in the Shortcuts app
  @available(iOSApplicationExtension 16, *)
  static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Open App"
  // Description of the action in the Shortcuts app
  @available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *)
  static var description: IntentDescription = IntentDescription("This action will open the selected book in the Booky app or navigate to the home library.", categoryName: "Navigation")
  // This opens the host app when the action is run
  static var openAppWhenRun = true
  
  @Parameter(title: "App", description: "The book to open in Booky", requestValueDialog: IntentDialog("Which book would you like to open?"))
  var apps: AppOption
  
  // An enum parameter
  @Parameter(title: "Navigation", description: "Choose whether to open a book or navigate to Booky's library", default: .book, requestValueDialog: IntentDialog("What would you like to navigate to?"))
  var navigation: NavigationType
  
  // How the summary will appear in the shortcut action.
  static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
    Summary("Open \(\.$apps)")
  }
  
  @MainActor // <-- include if the code needs to be run on the main thread
func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
     guard let selectedBook = appsDetail.first(where: { $0.appName == apps.rawValue }) else {
                 throw NSError(domain: "OpenBookError", code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Book not found."])
             }
             let userInfo: [String: Any] = ["selectedBook": [
                 "appName": selectedBook.appName,
                 "bundleId": selectedBook.bundleID,
                 "deepLinking": selectedBook.deepLinking,
             ]]
     
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("OpenBookCallback"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
     
     return .result()
   }
 }

We expected behaviours,

Open target app
Open my app
Again open target app (now target app already in background)
No need to again redirect to my app because app is in background.


I found your question confusing. Are you asking How to stop app opening/running when the app is already running in background by using AppShortcut
